# Single Quote coming before parameter in Spring JPA native Query

Tags: spring, spring-boot, hibernate, spring-data-jpa

Create a native sql query like following in the repository interface:

```java
@Query(value = "select Student.id as id , Student.name as studentname, Teacher.name as teachername from :firstdatabase inner join :seconddatabase on Student.id = Teacher.id;", nativeQuery = true)
List<StudentTeacher> getListStudentTeacher(   @Param("firstdatabase") String firstdatabase,   @Param("seconddatabase") String seconddatabase);
```

The database and table name are taken as Parameters from Controller Class like following:

```
List<StudentTeacher> studentTeacherList = studentTeacherRepo.getListStudentTeacher("database1.Student","database2.Teacher");
```

Getting The following Error :

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''database1.Student' inner join 'database2.Teacher' on Student.id = Teacher.id' at line 1.
```

My Question is how to do joins across database where database name is parameterized using native query and why  quotes are there before the parameters . we don't get quotes while using parameters in where condition. Kindly help regarding this

Comment: You shouldn't use parameterization like that. Also this is for security reasons else someone might use SQL Injection to drop databases etc. etc. So JDBC escapes/encodes parameters passed into the query.

Answer (score 0):

I think for tables with same fields, the best practis is to create a view unites your tables, then you request the view according the parameters of fields instead of the name of tables